# For loop in Shopify not working over number 9

Tags: html, for-loop, shopify, liquid

I'm having an issue with a for loop in Shopify. I'm sure it used to work, but I can't get it to work over the number 9 now.

```
{% assign productTag1 = Availability14 %} (in this example, the product has only 1 tag, which is Availability14)
{% assign avail_stop = false %}
      {% for j in (0..15) %}
        {% assign check_avail = 'Availability' | append:j %}
        {% if productTag1 contains check_avail %}
            {% assign avail_stop = true %}
            {% capture tag_name %}{{check_avail}}{% endcapture %}
            {% break %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if avail_stop %}
        {% assign availability = check_avail | remove:'Availability' | plus:0 %}
      {% endif %}
```

At the moment, I'm returning 1, not 14. I imagine it's something to do with the fact 14 includes a 1, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be easier to loop through the tags to find one that includes the word `availability`, remove the word `availability`, and get your value that way?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `{% break %}` statement in your `if`. Once the `if` becomes `true` it will exit the loop instantly.

If you want to skip the next code you must use `{% continue %}` not `{% break %}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The {% break %} is correct, because I want to exit the loop as soon as the if statement is complete. This works correctly where j is 1 to 9. But as soon as it gets to j=10 it always returns 1. If I used {% continue %} I'd always get a result of 15 :)

Comment: @whatdoyoumeannnn axa, I didn't understand your question then. Just switch the `contains` for equal operator `==` instead since `Availability1` is contained in `Availability14`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

On my mind this is an issue with conditional operator. As you said, 14 contains 1, so why not simply use strict conditional operator like this:

```
{% if productTag1 == check_avail %}
    {% assign has_stop = true %}
    {% break %}
{% endif %}
```

(or did I miss something?)